# Why does wait(100) cause synchronized method to fail in multi threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am referencing from Baeldung.com. Unfortunately, the article does not explain why this is not a thread safe code. [Article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-testing-multithreaded)

My goal is to understand how to create a thread safe method with the synchronized keyword.

**My actual result is**: The count value is 1.

```
package NotSoThreadSafe;

public class CounterNotSoThreadSafe {
  private int count = 0;
  public int getCount() { return count; }
  // synchronized specifies that the method can only be accessed by 1 thread at a time.
  public synchronized void increment() throws InterruptedException { int temp = count; wait(100); count = temp + 1; }
}
```

My expected result is: The count value should be 10 because of:

1. I created 10 threads in a pool.
2. I executed `Counter.increment()` 10 times.
3. I make sure I only test after the CountDownLatch reached 0.
4. Therefore, it should be 10. However, if you release the `lock` of synchronized using `Object.wait(100)`, the method become not thread safe.

```
package NotSoThreadSafe;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class CounterNotSoThreadSafeTest {
  @Test
  void incrementConcurrency() throws InterruptedException {
    int numberOfThreads = 10;
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfThreads);
    CounterNotSoThreadSafe counter = new CounterNotSoThreadSafe();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
      service.execute(() -> {
        try { counter.increment(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        latch.countDown();
      });
    }
    latch.await();
    assertEquals(numberOfThreads, counter.getCount());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you understand `wait()` to do, exactly? In particular, have you thought about the difference between `Object.wait()` and `Thread.sleep`?

Comment: Wait releases the monitor, so you read count first, then release the monitor, in the 100ms some other thread can enter the synchronized code and read count. Just to clarify, wait is not a pausing method.

Comment: @JonSkeet from my understanding, updating the count value require 3 operations. `read`, `increment`, `write`. The `Object.wait()` and `Thread.sleep()` is to force the `increment` and `write` operations to be executed at a later time. Upon closer inspection, `Thread.sleep()` does not release the lock while `Object.wait()` does release the lock.

Comment: Why should the result be 2? What does "fail" mean to you?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think Baeldung.com is trying to explain about synchronized keyword does not always mean thread safe method. Do you happen know how to explain why this code is not thread safe, without the `Object.wait()`?

Comment: @akuzminykh My bad, I have updated the post. The expected result is 10 because the unit test execute the `Counter.increment()` 10 times.

Comment: @kidfrom the synchronized code without the wait **is** thread-safe, why do you say it's not?

Comment: @Rocco I am refering to Baeldung.com, please kindly check the article I have attached above, it has a chance of thread interleaving, it demonstrate it by using `Object.wait(100)` without actually explaining further.

Comment: I would say it's just a really bad example - or at least, a very poorly explained one. If they'd used `Thread.sleep`, it would still be safe. To use `Object.wait` *without explaining that that effectively splits the synchronized method into two synchronized blocks* is really poor IMO :(

Comment: @kidfrom read my comment above, wait() releases the lock, so it actually breaks the synchronized method in two parts, ergo it's no longer atomic and no longer thread safe. That's it.

Comment: From the same site: [Wait and sleep](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-and-sleep) and [Thread safety](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has both of the classical concurrency problems: a race condition (a semantic problem) and a data race (a memory model related problem).

1. `Object.wait()` releases the object's monitor and another thread can enter into the synchronized block/method while the current one is waiting. Obviously, author's intention was to make the method atomic, but `Object.wait()` breaks the atomicity. As result, if we call `.increment()` from, let's say, 10 threads simultaneously and each thread calls the method 100_000 times, we get `count` < 10 * 100_000 almost always, and this isn't what we'd like to. This is a race condition, a logical/semantic problem. We can rephrase the code... Since we release the monitor (this equals to the exit from the synchronized block), the code works as follows (like two separated synchronized parts):

```
    public void increment() { 
        int temp = incrementPart1(); 
        incrementPart2(temp); 
    }
    
    private synchronized int incrementPart1() {
        int temp = count; 
        return temp; 
    }
    
    private synchronized void incrementPart2(int temp) {
        count = temp + 1; 
    }
```

and, therefore, our `increment` increments the counter not atomically. Now, let's assume that 1st thread calls incrementPart1, then 2nd one calls incrementPart1, then 2nd one calls incrementPart2, and finally 1st one calls incrementPart2. We did 2 calls of the `increment()`, but the result is 1, not 2.

2. Another problem is a data race. There is the Java Memory Model (JMM) described in the Java Language Specification (JLS). JMM introduces a Happens-before (HB) order between actions like volatile memory write/read, Object monitor's operations etc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5 HB gives us guaranties that a value written by one thread will be visible by another one. Rules how to get these guaranties are also known as Safe Publication rules. The most common/useful ones are:

- Publish the value/reference via a volatile field (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), or as the consequence of this rule, via the AtomicX classes
- Publish the value/reference through a properly locked field (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)
- Use the static initializer to do the initializing stores
  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)
- Initialize the value/reference into a final field, which leads to the freeze action (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).

So, to have the counter correctly (as JMM has defined) visible, we must make it volatile

```
private volatile int count = 0;
```

or do the read over the same object monitor's synchronization

```
public synchronized int getCount() { return count; }
```

I'd say that in practice, on Intel processors, you read the correct value without any of these additional efforts, with just simple plain read, because of TSO (Total Store Ordering) implemented. But on a more relaxed architecture, like ARM, you get the problem. Follow JMM formally to be sure your code is really thread-safe and doesn't contain any data races.

Comment: So if I have a `synchronized` setter, but the `count` attribute does not have `volatile`, it will cause problem in ARM, are the solutions 1: to use `synchronized` getter e.g. `synchronized void increment() {int temp = getCount(); wait(100); count = temp + 1; }` 2. to use `volatile` keyword to the `count` attribute?

Comment: I tested it, it seems concurrent logic can't work with `Object.wait()` which causes the lock to be released.

Comment: @kidfrom again :) in this particular code we have 2 different problems: 1 - a race condition - broken (by .wait()) atomicity. To fix it, you have to get rid of the wait(), which releases the monitor. If we need to simulate some workload, use, for example, Thread.sleep() instead. 2 - a data race. The updated counter may not be visible outside by a reader via getCount(). To fix this problem, declare the counter as a volatile field or add synchronized on the getter.

Comment: For problem 2. (after removing the `Object.wait()`) Do you mean that both the setter and getter needs to have `synchronized` in order to prevent data race because the setter method is accessed by multiple thread?, currently if I only use `synchronized` in the setter method, the test never fails, but I do use Intel chips, so I am not sure whether the code is thread safe even if the `Object.wait()` is removed.

Comment: @kidfrom right. JLS has specific part to describe how to write/save and read/load values/references in multithreaded environment to have updates visible to readers. To have the value written and read under the same lock (in our case - in a block synchronized on the same monitor) OR to do both write and read to/from a volatile field are 2 simplest ways to satisfy JMM requirements (there are some other ways to get Happens-before edge, but these 2 are the most simple/obvious/pragmatic ones)

Comment: @Anatolgy I will mark this as answer. However, when I test the increment() method `without the Object.wait();` with 20k of threads, the count value always between 19990 - 19999, i double check with `while (counter.getCount() != 20000) {}` to wait until the count value 20k before testing, resulting in failed test. In short, I should learn more about the JMM requirements you mention.

Comment: @kidfrom I hope you do something like  for (Thread t : threads) { t.join(); }  to make sure all incrementers have their work finished completely and only then you call getCount() ?

Comment: @kidfrom BTW, why do you need 20k threads and each one increments the counter only once? I'd say that it isn't a good idea to have so many threads in your application (you need much memory for stacks, a lot of CPU spent on context switching etc) In the real life you have 10x active threads, if most of them are parked/waiting for IO-1000x threads are OK.If you test multithreaded code,it's enough to use up to...10 threads, but each of them should live long enough to make 100K-100M operations to produce highly concurrent scenarious with higher calls/per sec ratio than in case of 100K-100M threads

Comment: @AnatolG if I use `thread.join`, the count value will be 20k because it will wait until all threads have been terminated before invoking `Counter.getCount()`. I am writing a study material for bootcamp to show that "even thread safe code can fail because it takes time to get the most updated value although it is a volatile attribute, just make sure you understand the volatile and the synchronized keyword"

Comment: @kidfrom then you may be interested in an example of using jcstress lib, which is an official tool for testing Java standard library, like https://vimeo.com/131395566 This is a good example why we need volatile

Comment: If you don't have a synchronized getter, the JIT can also cause problems. E.g. if the value is used in a loop, it could hoist the read out of the loop. So this will fail on CPUs with strong memory models as well.

Comment: @pveentjer right, this is a good illustration of how risky is to don't follow JMM literally) I'd say, we just get "undefined behaviour" without appropriate HB edges

Answer (score 1):

Why `int temp = count; wait(100); count = temp + 1;` is not thread-safe? One possible flow:

- First thread reads `count` (0), save it in `temp` for later, and waits, allowing second thread to run (lock released);
- second thread reads `count` (also 0), saved in `temp`, and waits, eventually allowing first thread to continue;
- first thread increments value from `temp` and saves in `count` (1);
- but second thread still holds the old value of `count` (0) in `temp` - eventually it will run and store `temp+1` (1) into `count`, not incrementing its new value.

<sup>very simplified, just considering 2 threads</sup>

In short: `wait()` releases the lock allowing other (synchronized) method to run.